# Redirects not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2.2

I have an .htaccess file with several lines. It does not work as expected. Mod_rewrite is enabled. RewriteLogLevel is set to 9.
The first two rules are there to forbid uris with a length more then 80 characters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.{80}
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

It does not seem to get evaluated as every test url passes through and it does not generate an error either.
I also tried:

```
RewriteRule .{80} - [F]
```

But that did not do the trick either. The process ends with a 404, not a 403.

This next rule is not working either. It used to work.

```
RewriteRule ^(\/)?([\w]+)$ /index.php [L]
```

The URI /Contact was always handled by this index.php.
Whatever URL I type I get a 404. I should get a 403 or a 200. Not a 404. What am I missing?
Apache has on all directories the permission to read, write and execute and on all files the permission to read and write.

The two urls for testing are:
127.0.0.4/asssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddd?p=s&s=psv

and

127.0.0.4/Contact

The alias for 127.0.0.4 used is considerate.lb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\S{80}
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as that variable might get overwritten due to presence of other rules in your .htaccess

Comment: Thank you, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: I added both urls that I use in my question. The mapping between considerate.lb and 127.0.0.4 works perfectly. The rule you served as an answer is the very first rule in the file. Your rule would not solve the question of why the second url (/Contact) does not work. Do you have any ideas why both rules do not work?

Comment: Exact same rule works on my Apache. You have to first make sure this .htaccess is in use. To verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I get that error indeed if I put something like RewriteLogLevel 9 in the file. And if I after that comment the loglevel out again, the internal server error disappears immediately.

Comment: ok can you test with just this rule in .htaccess and comment out everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was busy with other activities so I could not answer properly. I have added an answer of my own, because the code appeared not to be the problem. I will upvote your answer, because I am thankful for your efforts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution. The problem was not in the coding of the .htaccess. I replaced the file with a previous version, added the new lines to test the request and it worked all fine.

It is not a satisfactory solution, because it can happen again and I do not have any clue what caused the error. If someone knows the error, I would love to hear what might have been the exact cause and how to solve that properly. I would like to change the tags of the question as the current tags might be misleading (although other people might experience the same problem how apache handles a .htaccess file), but I do not know which tags I should use.